# shortening two subqueries into one subquery inside FROM clause

Tags: mysql

this query is correct but if there's someone that could shorten this query where it will only have one sub query as derived table or a subquery inside FROM clause, been stuck for 3 hours or so trying to shorten the query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.patient_id) AS Patient
    
FROM 
    patient p
    INNER JOIN transactions_detail td ON p.`patient_id` = td.`patient_id`
    INNER JOIN transactions_header th ON td.`tran_num` = th.`tran_num`
WHERE
    
    (p.`patient_id` NOT IN
        (SELECT 
            t_d1.patient_id
        FROM
            
            transactions_detail t_d1,
            transactions_header t_h1
        WHERE
            t_d1.`tran_num` = t_h1.`tran_num`
            AND t_h1.`tran_date` <= "2016-12-31"
            AND t_h1.`impacts` = "P"
        )
    OR 
    p.`patient_id` IN
        (SELECT 
            t_d2.patient_id
        FROM
            transactions_detail t_d2,
            transactions_header t_h2
        WHERE
            t_d2.`tran_num` = t_h2.`tran_num`
            AND t_h2.tran_date <= DATE_SUB("2017-01-01", INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
            AND t_h2.`impacts` = "P"
        )   
    )
    AND th.`tran_date` BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31"
    AND th.`impacts` = "P"
```

and this is what I am trying to work on to shorten the query up above

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.`patient_id`) AS Total
    
FROM 
    patient p
    INNER JOIN transactions_detail AS td ON p.`patient_id` = td.`patient_id`
    JOIN (SELECT 
            t_d.patient_id AS id,
            t_h.`tran_date` AS t_date,
            t_d.`tran_num` AS t_num
        FROM
            
            transactions_detail t_d,
            transactions_header t_h
        WHERE
            t_d.`tran_num` = t_h.`tran_num`
            AND t_h.`impacts` = "P"
    )AS q1 AND p.`patient_id` = q1.id
WHERE
    (q1.t_date <= "2016-12-31"
    OR
    q1.t_date <= DATE_SUB("2016-12-31", INTERVAL 3 YEAR))
    
    AND q1.t_date BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31"
```

Comment: This makes no sense: `q1.t_date <= "2016-12-31" OR q1.t_date <= DATE_SUB("2016-12-31", INTERVAL 3 YEAR)` That is equivalent to `q1.t_date <= "2016-12-31"` so not sure what logic you're trying to apply?

Comment: Can a `patient_id` show up in the table _both before and after_ "2016-12-31"?  Please describe, in English, the intent of the date tests.

Answer (score 1):

**You don't need self-joins here. You can use a simple `GROUP BY/HAVING` with conditional aggregation.**

- The `patient` join is unnecessary.
- The purpose of the date filters is unclear. You may want to re-check the logic.
- Ideally, instead of using `BETWEEN`, you should always use half-open intervals with dates `>= AND <`

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.patient_id) AS Patient
FROM (
    SELECT
      td.`patient_id`
    FROM transactions_detail td
    INNER JOIN transactions_header th
      ON td.`tran_num` = th.`tran_num`
    WHERE
      th.`impacts` = "P"
    GROUP BY
      td.`patient_id`
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN th.`tran_date` BETWEEN "2017-01-01" AND "2017-12-31" THEN 1 END) > 0
       AND (COUNT(CASE WHEN t_h1.`tran_date` <= "2016-12-31" THEN 1 END) = 0
         OR COUNT(CASE WHEN t_h1.`tran_date` <= "2014-01-01" THEN 1 END) > 0)   
) p
```